# Dataflow refresh issues

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

We have a scenario wherein a dataflow is conncted to Azure analysis service and it take ~1 hr 45 min to 2 hrs to refresh.

And sometimes it failes as the refresh takes more than 2 hrs with the error:

dataflow couldn’t be refreshed because there was a problem with one or more entities, or because dataflow capabilities were unavailable.

Refreshing an entity exceeded the 2 hour refresh limit.

But the same MDX/DAX query when we execute on AAS via SSMS or via PowerBI desktop takes <10 mins to refresh.

Also the logs enabled on AAS show that the query begin time and query end time when a dataflow is refreshing is <10 min but still the dataflow takes more than 1 hr to refresh.

So what might be the cause or scenario behind this?

Note : The count is more than 19,00,000 records

Comment: The number of records really shouldn't be a problem. Have you maybe included a timeout for the refresh? You can check that in the source options. 

And refreshing taking that long should not be happening for that amount of records. However, from the position I'm in I can't help you with making it faster. You could however choose to do an update every night, that way you at least have the data loaded in in the morning?

Comment: Hey @Max, My concern is more of why is cloud to cloud transfer taking >1 hr whereas the same data refresh on my on prem VM via SSMS is taking <10 mins

Comment: Maybe not enough computation power for Azure? A bad connection? I think these things are incredibly hard to deal with as an outsider since I can't have a look at your systems.

I have however searched for performance upgrades in cloud environments and I have found the following. https://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2019/12/azure-synapse-analytics-power-bi/ 
Maybe you can get some useful information from here?

Comment: Hey,
I have observed logs in AAS and saw that the query bein and query end was ~15 mins but still the refresh took more than 1 hr

Comment: Do you perhaps append data from different sources? For appending to work it would need to load everything in virtual memory, thus taking a long time and causing performance issues. If that is the case, I would suggest changing the appending / joining.

Lastly, here are a few more links that you might walk through and see what you can do:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/power-bi-reports-performance

http://blog.pragmaticworks.com/power-bi-performance-tips-and-techniques

https://www.sqlbi.com/topics/optimization/
(Credits go to Microsoft Support on the Power BI website)

Comment: Hey,
its a single source only:AAS

Comment: Then I'm terribly sorry Nandan, I've ran out of ideas.. Perhaps asking your question on the Power BI forums will help you? Try to give as much detail as possible. There are some real gurus on there that might be able to assist you (Also Microsoft employees!).